# Temporary instance in C++ with strings and c-strings

Tags: c++

So I have this code:

```cpp
void blocks(std::string URL, std::string auth)
{
    const char* cstr_url = URL.c_str();
    std::string s = ("Authorization: " + auth);
    const char* auth_header = s.c_str();
    (··· and so on ···)
}
```

And everything seems fine if we look in the "autos" field in Debug mode:

[image]

But if we try to change the code in a way that `("Authorization: " + auth)` is a temporary instance of the String class, in order to avoid declaring the `s` variable (and therefore saving space -at least, that's my purpose-):

```cpp
void blocks(std::string URL, std::string auth)
{
    const char* cstr_url = URL.c_str();
    const char* auth_header = ("Authorization: " + auth).c_str();
    (··· and so on ···)
}
```

...what we get in the Debug "autos" field is something quite different (lots of Ý chars):
[image]

<s>I thought C++ could support these kind of things (which I don't know how are they technically called, I assume "implicit instance" as an original name). I would swear Java could support these "implicit instances" though.</s>

So the actual question is, what's happening in here? Is there any workaround to avoid declaring an `s` variable?

Comment: `const char* auth_header = ("Authorization: " + auth).c_str();` bind `auth_header ` to a temporary that is destroyed at the end of the expression. You have a dangling pointer.

Comment: What would you do to fix this dangling pointer? @RichardCritten

Comment: You have to keep the result of `("Authorization: " + auth)` alive for as least as long as you want to use `auth_header` for

Comment: Seems like an XY problem -- why are you using `const char *` and c_str() at all?  It pretty much just exists for interacting with legacy C interfaces and should not be used otherwise.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I know. The reason is that I use the libcurl library whose strings are C strings, not C++ string objects.

Comment: @ElJaviLuki: in which case you should only call c_str() directly in the arguments to the libcurl calls -- don't create `const char *` tempvars.

Comment: @ElJaviLuki -- Just because another API uses C-style strings doesn't mean you have to emulate this in your own code.  As stated, you should work purely using `std::string`, and if an API wants a C-style string, then call the function using `string.c_str()`.

Answer (score 1):

The debug build has *very kindly* [thoroughly destroyed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations) the `char`s that ceased to exist after that statement, rather than leaving them in a state where you might think things were ok.

The C++ name for such things is "rvalue" (and specifically "prvalue"), which denotes the [value category](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) of the expression `("Authorization: " + auth)`. Rvalues are objects that are about to be destroyed.

`auth_header` is now an invalid pointer, and doing *anything* with it (besides re-assigning it) has undefined behaviour.